# I want to create a javascript script in a heredoc

Tags: javascript, php

Hy,
I want to create a javascript in a heredoc ,is this possible ?
and do you have an example ?

```
function redirect_to_j ( $location = NULL) {
    if($location !=NULL) {
$js = <<<JS
<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.location.replace("$location");
</script>

JS;

header("Content-type: text/javascript");
echo $js;
exit();
    }
}
```

it prints the code on screen but does not run the javascript

Comment: A Javascript file shouldn't have the HTML `<script>` element around the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can have either HTML containing JavaScript or you can have JavaScript.

You appear to be outputting a fragment of HTML with a content-type header claiming that it is a JavaScript.

Either:

1. Get rid of the `header()` statement and embed the whole thing in an HTML document *or*
2. Get rid of the script tags.

Then, if you go with option 2, you'll need to load the script into an HTML document to execute it. Use a `<script src="yourphp.js"></script>`.

---

If your goal is to redirect the user the you should probably be doing it in HTTP not JavaScript anyway.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/example/");
exit();
```